# Requesting features in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I try to ask some questions in chat in general, the members in the room sometimes don’t respond me (I can understand it may be they are discussing some other topic).

So then after some lots of chat the page jumps to new. Again if I want get a feed from the same question I need to type the whole question again. Can we have a feature of highlighting our own text?

Comment: Did you try this: reply to your own question, then type @thepersonyouwanttotalk,  then say something like "did you see my message?".

Comment: If this is happening regularly, there's a possibility that people do not wish to answer those particular questions. There are numerous reasons why this may be the case.

Comment: @DiculSmerd please don't ask people to upvote your question. It's useless and only cause the opposite.

Comment: I did not downvote, not upvote either. @ShadowWizard is correct. Asking for upvote is impolite. Please don't do that.

Comment: `Can we have a feature of highlighting our own text?` - My text is highlighted in chat, and easy to see when I backscroll. You should include the version of browser you are using in your question if that's going to be a factor. You might also want to tell us which chatroom you are trying to participate in and an example of one of your posts.

Comment: Please make your question/feature title more descriptive. Vague titles are going to annoy the community and  don't help anyone know what you are asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most of SE - it's frowned upon to use chat to ask questions - especially considering we have perfectly good Q&A sites. Obviously - folks *talk* about problems and questions, but generally if there's an ongoing conversation, it's a bad time and many people are disinclined to encourage people from asking questions on chat.

So more or less - if someone ignores your question, it's likely to be intentional and is a quirk of SE chat culture. Asking again rarely does any good. Chat's not a great place for questions - it's a great place for *discussion*.

In theory you could copy a link to what you said in chat, paste it and get it oneboxed, but this is unlikely to get a better result.

Comment: Yeah, bumping your own messages in chat will cause a bad reaction, eventually.

Comment: I didn't want to assume, but I assumed

Comment: Meh, people are pretty lenient on questions, especially on science chats. However, if the person asking comes with the attitude that the chat owes them a response, then that's when things might get ugly. Most SE chats, as opposed to busy SO chats I presume (and Root Access ಠ_ಠ), don't have too many fast-paced ongoing discussions during the day.

Comment: Yeah, in the Physics room for example, we definitely entertain questions which call for a discussion as a response, or some questions which are just plain off topic on the main site, depending on the level of interest from people in the room. Of course there are some questions which should go on the main site, and we tell people so when they ask them, but that's at least one chat room where I would _not_ say it's frowned upon to use chat to ask questions in general.

Comment: I've personally found that talking about problems works better than asking questions - but this is easier once you get familiar with a room and its denizens.